# One table from many source(One to One) - Database Design

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a 'Text' table, the text table may came from different source, like Tweet, SMS, Email, etc. and each source have their own log, and Text is came from the source. so i came with some solution, but i don't know which is the best.

**Solution 1 :**

```
Text(
text_id PK
content
source_type (tweet, sms, email, etc)
source_id (can't be FK since it may contain sms_id, tweet_id, or email_id)
)

Tweet(
tweet_id PK
tweet_text
tweet_username
etc...
)

Sms(
sms_id PK
sms_text
sender_number
etc...
)

Email(
email_id PK
email_text
email_sender
etc...
)
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
Text(
text_id PK
content
sms_id FK
tweet_id FK
email_id FK
)

Tweet(
tweet_id PK
tweet_text
tweet_username
etc...
)

Sms(
sms_id PK
sms_text
sender_number
etc...
)

Email(
email_id PK
email_text
email_sender
etc...
)
```

Please note that one 'Text' only came from one source.

so if I use solution 2, let say the source is came from sms then the data will look like this

```
Text(
12
'the text'
333
null
null
)

Sms(
333
'the text'
0818833733664
etc...
)
```

so which is the best approach ?

**UPDATE :**

I miss a big part on my question, and that's are may fault, sorry for that. In my case the Text also may came from a csv(excell) file. which mean one file may have many text, because the file is a dump for many text(coma or row separated). SMS, Tweet, and Email relation with Text is one to one, but File with Text is One to Many
so the big missing part in my question is the File Table

```
File(
file_id PK
file_name
etc..
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an additional table called `text_source` and then have each source (i.e. SMS, Email, etc) reference it via FK `text_source_id`. That way, you can have your `text` table just have a `text_source_id`.

i.e.

`Text` table  --FK--> `text_source` table <--FK-- `SMS`, `Email`, `Tweet`

Comment: Did you mean Like this, Text(text_id, content, source_id(FK)), Text_Source(source_id(PK), sms_id(FK), tweet_id(FK), email_id(FK)) ?

Comment: Not quite. Text_Source(source_id(PK)), Tweet(tweet_id(PK), source_id(FK), other_columns...), SMS(sms_id(PK), source_id(FK)), etc. Make sense? It adds a table in between the Text table and the three source tables, so you only have to reference the one Text_Source table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i really appreciate. but i think, i miss a big part on my question, and that's are may fault, sorry for that. In my case the Text also may came from a csv(excell) file. which mean one file may have many text, because the file is a dump for many text(coma or row separated). SMS, Tweet, and Email relation with text is one to one, but File with Text is One to Many. Thanks before